# Saving JavaScript functionality on Reload?

Tags: javascript, html, button, local-storage, addeventlistener

I am working on a budget app with a form that adds expenses to a list which holds their name and value. Every time the Add Expense button is clicked, it adds a paragraph tag as below:

```
subListContent.innerHTML = `<p class="product">${expenseName}</p><p class="amount">$${expenseValue}</p>`;
```

Each paragraph has an edit button and a delete button that lets you edit the amount or delete the individual item from the list.

Upon adding the expense, the amounts (income/expenses) are saved to local storage. The paragraph tags (the list of expenses) is also saved to local storage. Upon reload, the page loads the list of expenses again.

```
expensesArray = list.innerHTML;
saveExpenseArray(expensesArray)
```

However, when the page reloads, the edit button and the delete button does not work anymore. Does anyone know how to keep the edit and delete button functionality working?

Thank you

I tried creating two variables "editStart" and "deleteStart" that look up the buttons by ID.

I try to create button functionality once the page loads by doing the following:

```
 editStart.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modifyElement(editStart, true);
    });
deleteStart.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modifyElement(deleteStart);
});
```

(I place these two at the bottom of the page so scoping is not an issue)

However, the error comes up that addEventListener is not a function or the following error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Does anyone know what I can do in this case?

Below is the two functions that let you edit/delete the items and add the lists to the expenses list respectively:

```
//Modify list elements function

const modifyElement = (element, edit = false) => {
    let parentDiv = element.parentElement;
    let currentBalance = balanceValue.innerText;
    let currentExpense = expenditureValue.innerText;
    let parentAmount = parentDiv.querySelector(".amount").innerText;
    if (edit) {
        let parentText = parentDiv.querySelector(".product").innerText;
        productTitle.value = parentText;
        userAmount.value = parentAmount;
        disableButtons(true);
    }
    balanceValue.innerText = parseInt(currentBalance) + parseInt(parentAmount);
    expenditureValue.innerText = parseInt(currentExpense) - parseInt(parentAmount);
    parentDiv.remove();
};

// Create list function

const listCreator = (expenseName, expenseValue) => {
    let subListContent = document.createElement("div");
    subListContent.classList.add("sublist-content", "flex-space");
    list.appendChild(subListContent);
    subListContent.innerHTML = `<p class="product">${expenseName}</p><p class="amount">$${expenseValue}</p>`;
    let editButton = document.createElement("button");
    editButton.classList.add("fa-solid", "fa-pen-to-square", "edit");
    editButton.style.fontSize = "1.2em";
    editButton.setAttribute("id", "edit");
    editButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modifyElement(editButton, true);
    });
    let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.classList.add("fa-solid", "fa-trash-can", "delete");
    deleteButton.style.fontSize = "1.2em";
    deleteButton.setAttribute("id", "delete");
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modifyElement(deleteButton);
    });
    subListContent.appendChild(editButton);
    subListContent.appendChild(deleteButton);
    expensesArray = list.innerHTML;
    saveExpenseArray(expensesArray)
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(subListContent);
};
```

Comment: Try changing the `editButton.addEventListener("click", () => {modifyElement(editButton, true);});` part to: `editButton.setAttribute("onclick", "modifyElement(editButton, true)");` and the other one alike.

Comment: @SamuNemeth but why? `addEventListener` is a more modern approach to setting inline event listeners - [which you should avoid doing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) in the first place.

Comment: At the moment when `addEventListener` is executed buttons are not visible at the page, so the selector can't select them. If you do `console.log(editStart)` it will gives you `null`, so try put that piece of code below the code where you are rendering buttons (fetching paragraphs from localstorage)